# Sensors report bad data after device is shaken

Tags: android, android-sensors, galaxy, s5

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Register a listener for the gravity sensor with normal sampling period. Either use your own code (basic example below) or just install [My Sensors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kfodor.MySensors), making sure to set the sensor update rate to *Normal* via the menu.

   ```
   Sensor gravitySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
   sensorManager.registerListener(callback, gravitySensor, SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   ```
2. Observe the sensor output. The Y axis (`event.values[1]`) should report ~9.7 when the device is upright.
3. Give the device a hard, quick shake/swing once or twice. Then hold it upright again.
4. Look at the sensor output after doing this:

   - For the first 2 seconds, the Y axis value transitions from 9.7 to -9.7.
   - For the next 6 seconds, the Y axis value remains inverted (-9.7).
   - For the next 2 seconds, the Y axis value transitions back to 9.7.

This look like a bug to me because it seems completely counter-intuitive to have bad data for 10 seconds every time the user shakes or swings the device.

#### Device details

- Using a Samsung Galaxy S5 (G900I)
- Running Android 5.0 (also happened after upgrading to Android 6)
- Affected sensors

  - Gravity Sensor (Samsung Electronics) (Version 3)
  - MPL Rotation Vector (Invensense) (Version 1)
  - MPL Game Rotation Vector (Invensense) (Version 1)
  - Orientation Sensor (Samsung Electronics) (Version 1)

#### My questions

1. Is this normal behaviour for this device? (Does it happen on *your* Galaxy S5?)
2. Is this normal behaviour for Android devices in general? (Does it happen on *your* Android device(s) with the above sensor types?)
3. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial workaround: use a fast sampling rate

The problem no longer occurs when I set the sensor sampling rate to any of the following:

- `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME`
- `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`
- `54999` or lower

Unfortunately, if the sensor is already being listened to by another app, the sampling rate that was requested by the *other* app is used instead of the value requested by my app. So if another app is already listening to the sensor with `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`, for example, my app only gets sensor updates at that rate, leaving my app completely unable to workaround the bug.